# Using foldl/foldr to drop elements from a String

Tags: haskell

If it's possible I'd want to use foldl or foldr to drop the chars 'A','T','C' and 'G' from a String ['A'..'Z']

I tried this:

```
string = ['A'..'Z']
test string = foldl (\string (x:xs) -> 
                     if x == 'A' then drop ('A' string) 
                     else test xs) string
```

However it doesn't work because drop does not work with Char. Is there a way to do this using a fold function?

Comment: `drop ('A' string)`?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why this does not work. Can you explain (*duck debugging*) why you think the above fragment should do what you want it to do?

Comment: Adenine, thymine, cytosine and guanine?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: my guess as well. But nevertheless, It is very weird why somebody expects this to work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i did not expect it to work though, it was an attempt

Comment: @MiguelConceicao: so you make an attempt by writing an algorithm you do not expect to work? That's not much better than writing some random snippet. Perhaps it can help by first describing how you think your program is supposed to work, or by writing a recursive version.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you always expect your code to work the first time you try something new? That accusatory question isn't very friendly.

Comment: @amalloy: not at all. What I mean is that if you write some piece of code, one of course has some solving strategy in mind. The fact that some parts do not turn out to work very well is very likely and happens a lot. But one usually has some idea how to solve the problem in the first place.

Comment: I think your first question, "how did you think this would work" is a good one to develop the right thought processes, I just objected to the followup. The edited version is less confrontational: thanks for that.

Comment: I wonder if "Is there a way to do this using a fold function?" is really the question you meant to ask. Are you asking this because fold is how you first thought of to approach this, or because you genuinely want to use fold for some reason? If this is just because fold was your first guess about how to implement this, then there's a quite short non-fold-based answer: ```test = filter (`notElem` "ACGT")```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `foldr` as a *catamorphism*

One of the aspects we can use here is that `foldr` is a *catamorphism* over a list `[]`. Indeed we can write:

```
foldr (:) []
```

and if we enter a list, we will obtain exactly the same list:

```
Prelude> foldr (:) [] [1,4,2,5]
[1,4,2,5]
```

Why? Conceptually `foldr` iterates over the list *right-to-left*. It uses an accumulator that first is `[]`, for every element in the list `x`, it calls the function with `x` and `a` (`a` being the accumulator) as arguments. The result obtained in the new accumulator that is the used to process the new element.

So:

```
   foldr (:) [] [1,4,2,5]
-> foldr (:) ((:) 5 []) [1,4,2]
```

Now `(:)` is a constructor that takes a *head* (here `5`) and a tail (here `[]`), and constructs a list that starts with the head as first element, followed by the elements of the tail, so `(:) 5 []` is equal to `[5]`.

```
-> foldr (:) [5] [1,4,2]
-> foldr (:) [2,5] [1,4]
-> foldr (:) [4,2,5] [1]
-> foldr (:) [1,4,2,5] []
-> [1,4,2,5]
```

So if we pass a list through `foldr (:) []` we obtain the same list.

## Why is this useful?

What does this has to do with our problem? Well if we want to perform a filtering, we can use another function istead of `(:)`. We should only prepend if the character is not an `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, or `'T'`. So some function that works with:

```
f x xs | <some-condition> = x : xs
       | otherwise = xs
```

Now in order to check if a character `x` is not `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, or `'T'`, we can write:

```
not (elem x "ACGT")
```

So the function is now:

```
f x xs | not (elem x "ACGT") = x : xs
       | otherwise = xs
```

the otherwise case must xs instead of the whole list

or shorter:

```
f x | not (elem x "ACGT") = (x:)
    | otherwise = id
```

We can also swap the output and thus remove the `not`:

```
f x | elem x "ACGT" = id
    | otherwise = (x:)
```

Thus now we can use that function `f` instead of `(:)` with a `where` clause:

```
filterAcgt :: [Char] -> [Char]
filterAcgt = foldr f []
    where f x | elem x "ACGT" = id
              | otherwise = (x:)
```

and now we can generate a sequence of `'A'..'Z'` without `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'` and `'T'`:

```
Prelude> filterAcgt ['A'..'Z']
"BDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do as follows;

```
Prelude> foldr (\c a -> if (elem c $ "ATCG") then a else c : a) "" ['A'..'Z']
"BDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ"
```